# Exception in Tkinter Callback: Bool type object not callable

Tags: python, tkinter

So I was working on this Tkinter login-register interface, when I ran into an error on my registration side. I initially thought it to be because of poorly implemented classes, but that wasn't it.
Here is my code:

```
def getinfo(event):
    register_window = Tk(screenName='RegisterWindow')
    register_hfont = Font(root=register_window, family='product sans', size=18)
    register_nfont = Font(root=register_window, family='product sans', size=10)
    head_label = Label(register_window, text='Welcome!')
    head_label.grid(row=0)
    head_label.configure(font=register_hfont)
    user_label = Label(register_window, text='Username ')
    user_label.grid(row=2)
    username_entry = Entry(register_window)
    username_entry.grid(row=2, column=2)
    user_label.configure(font=register_nfont)
    pass_label = Label(register_window, text='Password ')
    pass_label.grid(row=3)
    password_entry = Entry(register_window)
    password_entry.grid(row=3, column=2)
    pass_label.configure(font=register_nfont)
    email_label = Label(register_window, text='Email ')
    email_label.grid(row=4)
    email_entry = Entry(register_window)
    email_entry.grid(row=4, column=2)
    email_label.configure(font=register_nfont)
    name_label = Label(register_window, text='Name ')
    name_label.grid(row=5)
    name_entry = Entry(register_window)
    name_entry.grid(row=5, column=2)
    name_label.configure(font=register_nfont)

    print('data submissions successful')
    submit_button = Button(register_window, text='Register')
    submit_button.bind('<Button-1>', register(username_entry, password_entry, name_entry, email_entry))
    submit_button.grid(row=7, column=1)
    register_window.mainloop()
    if RegisterVar:
        register_window.destroy()
    else:
        pass


def register(eusername, epassword, ename, eemail):
    uid = eusername.get()
    pwd = epassword.get()
    name = ename.get()
    email = eemail.get()
    print('function called')
    register_command = 'insert into logininfo values("'+uid+'","'+pwd+'","'+name+'","'+email+'");'
    cursor.execute(register_command)
    RegisterVar = True
    print('Registration Successful!')
    return True
```

When i clicked the submit_button object, i ran into this error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\adity\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
TypeError: 'bool' object is not callable
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What does this have to do with MySQL?

Comment: Well, the registration was happening through MySQL. I may be mistaken in my use of tags, sorry, I am very new on this site.

Comment: The *question* has nothing to do with MySQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing `submit_button.bind` the *result of calling* `register` as opposed to the function itself (which tinter will call).

Comment: Hi! Thanks, I was able to bypass this by using a lambda function. Thanks for the quick response!